# NSOpenPanel doesn't search folder if allowedTypes are selected

Tags: cocoa, xamarin.mac, nsopenpanel

I use following code to open panel, it should give you ability to choose only images

```
    openPanel = NSOpenPanel.OpenPanel;
    openPanel.FloatingPanel = true;
    openPanel.CanChooseFiles = true;
    openPanel.AllowsMultipleSelection = true;
    openPanel.CanChooseDirectories = false;
    openPanel.AllowedFileTypes = new string [] { "png", "jpeg", "jpg", "gif" };

    openPanel.BeginSheet (this.View.Window, (obj) => {
        if (obj == 1 && openPanel.Urls != null) {}
```

when it opens , I'm not able to search folder .... but if I enable `CanChooseDirectories` property if will search folders too ..

How to force NSOpenPanel to search folders, without allow choosing directory?

Comment: I do not see a any difference with the `CanChooseDirectories` option. Besides being able to choose a folder for opening. Can you give more details? What do you mean by 'search'

Comment: where the open panel is opened , here is search bar, in the top right corner , where I'm not able to search folders

Comment: @svn I tried this. When `CanChooseDirectories` is true, I can search for folders. If it is false, searching for "Documents" doesn't find anything.